# Why is there no race around condition in NOR SR latch when S=R=0(initially)?

Tags: logic-gates, flipflop, nand

When the IC gets connected to the Vcc+, both the NOR gates get the input 0 and 0 (low) which yields the output 1. Now since both the outputs are again connected as one of the input to each of the NOR gate, the gate should yield 0 (Since the inputs now are 1 and 0). Now since the 2 inputs are again 0, the same thing should happen over and over again just as it happens in case of JK flip-flop where NAND gate is used while J=K=CLK=1.

**Note: I haven't practically tested if the same race around condition occurs or not.**

Comment: You've touched on a very common issue in logic design. For simple devices such as single flip-flop and latch ICs, the initial state on power-up *is* undefined. More complex ICs such as microcontrollers typically include power-on-reset (PoR) circuitry that forces all of the flip-flops into a known state until the power supply stabilizes. It is also worth noting that the "textbook" designs you see are idealized models. Internally, latches and flip-flops are typically implemented using [transmission gates](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/4/4243.html).

Comment: So why does it not be uncertain in JK flip-flop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's theoretically possible they could oscillate in this way for a time, but extremely unlikely.  In reality, one gate is a little faster and wins the race.  The other might get a blip out before the propagation delay is over, but it will always be slower than the first one and quickly stabilize.

Comment: I read it somewhere that it depends on the rise time of the gate which is uncertain so anything can happen.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow gate rise times vary with technology (and temperature, and manufacturing variations).  For at least some technologies (all the TTL and old-style 74C and 4000-series CMOS) a gate that's back-connected to itself will tend to stabilize at some mid-level voltage rather than oscillating.  In that case the transition from the metastable state will be smooth and without much drama.  I'm pretty sure (but I haven't done the test, nor seen any literature) that 74HC and newer series will, or at least may, oscillate.

Comment: Why do newer gates tend to oscillate more compared to the older ones?

Comment: So why does it not be uncertain in JK flip-flop?

Comment: It does exist, so you either implement a design that is robust enough to deal with the  problem or you synchronize the outputs with clocks to eliminate the problem.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat It does exist, but why is it not uncertain in that case?